# Show uniform convergence on a compact set given local comparison

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

For $z \in \Bbb{C}$, $n\geq 1$ let,
$$a_n(z) := e^{-z/n}\left(e^{z/n}-1-\dfrac{z}{n}\right)$$
Then, for $z \neq 0$, $$ \left(\dfrac{n}{z}\right)^2 a_n(z) \xrightarrow[n\rightarrow +\infty]{} \dfrac{1}{2} 
 \quad \text{ therefore }\quad |a_n(z)| \underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim} \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{|z|^2}{n^2} $$
Hence the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} a_n(z)$ converges absolutely, but given a compact subset $K$ of $\Bbb{C}$, I feel one can get more, namely,
$$\sup_{z \in K} \{ |a_n(z)| \} =: \Vert a_n\Vert_{\infty}^K = \mathcal{O} \left( \dfrac{1}{n^2} \right) $$
that would give us the uniform convergence of $\sum a_n(z)$ on any compact subset. But I cannot think of any proper explanation at the moment. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

---

**Edit:** After thinking about it, I might have found a more general approach. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\Bbb{C}$, then as $$ f(w) := \dfrac{e^{-w}}{w^2}(e^w-1-w) \xrightarrow[w\rightarrow 0]{} \dfrac{1}{2} $$
there is $r>0$ such that $$\forall w \in D(0,r), |f(w)|\leq 1$$
As $K$ is compact, it is bounded therefore there is some $M_K>0$ such that $K \subset D(0,M_K)$. Therefore, there exists $N_K \in \Bbb{N}$ such that,
$$\forall n \geq N_K, \forall z \in K, \left| \dfrac{z}{n} \right| \leq r.$$
Hence,
$$\forall n \geq N_K, \forall z \in K, \quad \left|f\left(\dfrac{z}{n}\right)\right| \leq 1,$$
which yields,
$$\forall n \geq N_K, \forall z \in K, \quad |a_n(z)| \leq \dfrac{|z|^2}{n^2} \leq \dfrac{M_K^2}{n^2}.$$
Therefore, $$ \forall n \geq N_K, \quad \sup_{z \in K} |a_n(z)| \leq \dfrac{M_K^2}{n^2}.$$
Whence the normal convergence of $\sum a_n(z)$ on any compact subset of $\Bbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can show that the function
$$
 f(w) = e^{-w}(e^w-1-w)
$$
satisfies
$$ \tag{$*$}
 |f(w)| \le \frac 12 |w|^2 e^{|w|}
$$
for all $w \in \Bbb C$. Setting $w = z/n$ then gives the estimate
$$
 |a_n(z)| \le \frac 12 \frac{|z|^2}{n^2} e^{|z|/n}
\le \frac 12 \frac{|z|^2}{n^2} e^{|z|}
$$
and since $|z|^2e^{|z|}$ is bounded on a compact set $K$, the desired conclusion
$$
\sup_{z \in K} \{ |a_n(z)| \}  = \mathcal{O} \left( \dfrac{1}{n^2} \right)
$$
follows.

It remains to prove $(*)$: First we determine the power series of the function $f$:
$$
\begin{align}
f(w) &= 1-e^{-w}(1+w) \\
& = 1 - \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}w^k\right) \cdot (1+w) \\
& = \sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k\left( -\frac{1}{k!}+\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\right) w^k \\
& = \sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{k-1}{k!} w^k \, .
\end{align}
$$
Now we can estimate the absolute value:
$$
\begin{align}
 |f(w)| &\le \sum_{k=2}^\infty  \frac{k-1}{k!} |w|^k \\
& = \frac 12 |w|^2 \sum_{k=2}^\infty  \frac{2(k-1)}{k!} |w|^{k-2} \\
& = \frac 12 |w|^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{2(k+1)}{(k+2)!} |w|^{k} \\
& \le \frac 12 |w|^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{k!} |w|^{k} \\
& = \frac 12 |w|^2 e^{|w|} \, .
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for this clear and well-written answer. It perfectly solves the problem. Before marking your answer as accepted, I would like to take some time to think about this problem more thoroughly, and try to come with another approach if possible, my intuition tells me there must be another way to tackle it, but I might be wrong. Thank you again, have a nice evening.

Comment: I tried answering my question in the edit, do you think it is correct?

Comment: @Axel: Yes, I think it is.